# Xamarin Essentials - MediaPicker - Serial version and packages problems

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget, xamarin.essentials

Fine?

I have been trying to user Xamarin Essentials Media picker in order to take pictures and shoot videos in my app. The documentation is pretty straight forward and does not impose such a big challenge to implement the code.

Although, I have been experiencing some issues regarding Xamarin Essentials nuget package version and other related libraries.

So, here goes a brief explanation of the process that I've been through these last days:

It is important to highlight that the application was running normally before that.

Firstly, I wrote the following piece of code:

```
        public async Task TakePicture(object param)
        {
            try
            {
                var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
                CanTakePhoto = false;
                ShowRemakePhotoButton = CanRemake;
            }
            catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
            {
                // Feature is now supported on the device
            }
            catch (PermissionException pEx)
            {
                // Permissions not granted
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
        {
            // canceled
            if (photo == null)
            {
                PhotoPath = null;
                return;
            }
            // save the file into local storage
            var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
            using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
            using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

            PhotoPath = newFile;
        }
```

As expected, I needed to add Xamarin.Essentials nuget to both my android and shared projects in order to have access to MediaPicker API. I did so and installed the latest available version (1.6.1), and that caused the following errors when compiling.

*java/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)[B :  invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 13)*

*com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in androidx.browser.trusted.ConnectionHolder.getServiceWrapper:()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;: invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 13)    D:\minimo\repos\Terram\TerramAPP2.Android\COMPILETODALVIK*

*com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: ERROR in androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsService$1.newSessionInternal:(Landroid/support/customtabs/ICustomTabsCallback;Landroid/app/PendingIntent;)Z: invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 13)
D:\minimo\repos\Terram\TerramAPP2.Android\COMPILETODALVIK*

I tried the most obvious solution, that is raising the API minimum level to > 23. But that didn't work.

After some research, I found that a possible solution would be changing from dx and proguard to r8 and d8 shrinker and dex compiler.

That action results in no building error, but a runtime error instead. The error occurs on the "OnCreate" method of MainActivity.cs file, on the lines of the following code snippet:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, 15, 17, 22));

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            UserDialogs.Init(this);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Forms.SetFlags("SwipeView_Experimental");
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState); //<- this is the line where the error occurs
            Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(this.Application);
            LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "associes-se ao serviço", (sender) => StartBackgroundLocationService());
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "desassocies-se ao serviço", (sender) => StopBackgroundLocationService());
        }
```

Apparently, it is related to googlePlayServices showed in more details on the error massege below:

***Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException:** 'Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.minimo.agro-45tafg5QXIG3cUXxGmGhkw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.minimo.agro-45tafg5QXIG3cUXxGmGhkw==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.minimo.agro-45tafg5QXIG3cUXxGmGhkw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]'*

After some research, I found that if any package is related to a given GooglePlayService package, it may cause this error if they do not have the same version. I've been tryied to set all the nuget packages that had any relationship to GooglePlayServices to a specific version that would not cause this conflict, but also without success.

Project settings:

- VS version 16.10.2
- android target API 29/30
- tested both dx/proguard and r8/d8
- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012
- Target Framework - .NET Standard 2.0

Hope anyone can help me figure this one out!

Thanks!

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated the question and removed the images! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @BPorto From [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android), you need to add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`,`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`,`CAMERA` permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, then I use doc sample to test, take photo, and save stream in `/data/user/0/com.companyname.gensture/cache/aad01af5ef564eb0aeee817779fb69df.jpg`. I use Xamarin.forms 5.0 version.